# Centering X Axis ticks in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have tried various transforms, but I can't seem to find any way to center the x axis ticks below each bar. Currently, they are aligned left. Here is my xAxisScale:

```
var xAxisScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(values[0]['name']),
             d3.time.day.offset(new Date(values[values.length - 1].name), 1)])
    .range([0, w]);
```

Here is a JS fiddle for what I currently have:

http://jsfiddle.net/NxtG9/

Comment: It looks like you have two different x scales. Using just one will make everything line up automatically.

Comment: Don't I need a separate one for the dates? I'm new to d3, so could you elaborate?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/) is an example that uses only one.